# XForms and restxq application

Tags: rest, xforms, basex, xsltforms

I am trying to create a simple interface, that will use XForms to display a button that say "Drop a Database". I then want to be able to invoke a RestXQ document called `dropdatabase.xqm` which is called when the button on the form is clicked. I am using BaseX. I saved my XForm in a file called `onlydel.xml` in the `basex/webapp/static` folder.  I created my RestXQ program called dropdatabase.xqm and saved it to my `basex/webapp` folder. I have created a database called `patients`.

**xforms**: The contents of `onlydel.xml` is:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">     
<head>
<title>XFORMS IN XHTML</title>       
<model xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" id="order-model">
<instance>
<soap xmlns="">
</soap>
</instance>
<submission action="/dropdatabase" method="post" id="s06"/>

</model>
</head>

<body>
<h2>DATABASE</h2>
<div style="float:center;">
<fieldset style="width:50%">
<xf:submit submission="s06"><xf:label>Drop A Database</xf:label></xf:submit>
</fieldset></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RestXQ** :The contents of `dropdatabase.xqm` is:

```
module namespace _ = 'http://exquery.org/ns/restxq';
(:~
 : Deletes the blog database and redirects the user to the main page.
 :)
declare 
%restxq:path("/dropdatabase")
%restxq:GET
function _:dropdatabase()
{
   (db:drop("patients"))
};
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
 Stopped at /home/ubuntu/basex/webapp/dropdatabase.xqm, 10/13:
[XUST0001] StaticFunc expression: no updating expression allowed.
```

The help I need is:

1. Can I do something like this with the code I have written.
2. What is the reason for the error and a solution to eliminate the error too would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems quite clear to me: `db:drop()` is an updating expression and is hence not allowed at this point. You have to mark the function as an updating function by using the `%updating` annotation.

Comment: That definitely helped remove the error..Thanks very much dirkk. I however did not get the database to be dropped. Can you see where there could be a problem.

Comment: I think I got that...I had to change the GET to a POST